# How can I make javascript/jQuery trigger on new php/AJAX page requests without refresh?

Tags: php, jquery, angularjs, ajax, ionic-framework

I have jQuery code which changes my div element style on documents ready :

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  if ('#bgbg:not(:empty)') {
    $('#bgbg').css({ 
      'background-color':'#fff',
      'background-image':'none !important'
    });
  }
});
```

**I have no refreshes between pages, there are a lot of users created, and this function only triggers once - on first call and stays in that users profile.**

*For example :* 
*First user -* http://linkt/#/app/user/o9OI9x3zGH *(Works here) but then when I go to next users : Second user -* http://ssd.lt/#/app/user/yHCUnPi9fd *- its not working* - still working on the same first user.

jQuery works only first time or after refresh (F5) - how to make it work on all pages requests without refresh ?

I use : AngularJS, ionic, jQuery

Comment: `$(document).ready()` executes a function when the document is ready, that's why your function is only executed ... when the document is ready

Comment: I know, how to make it load on new page request - when url changes ?

Comment: If the url changes, your page is refreshed and then your document is ready again so it should be called once more

Comment: Use jQuery `setInterval` function and place you ajax code in that function

Comment: But its not calling  - and I dont see refresh, only url change. Maby You can show me example of something familiar ?

Comment: Create a function that contains the `if ('#bgbg:not(:empty)') ...` code and call that function on document ready and when the URL changes. Document ready is only called once (which it should).